# How to increment and decrement the value of textview in listview?

Tags: android

when I am increasing and decreasing the value of textview of first row and then I go to second row it is taking the previous value when I increase and decrease its value. I am using a counter and incrementing the counter by fixed amount on click of button.

Comment: please post your code...here

Comment: show your code only then we can understand

Comment: obviously you need to store every item value in some variable ... obviously not in View itself ... the common(and well documented) way is to store data in underlaying model (or - if you are using Cursor - in fx: SparseArray)

Comment: Can you post your adapter code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the values modified in a `ListView`, then maintaining values in a `List` will help you achieve it.

For eg: When you are updating a value in the `ListView`, just update the value in the `List` such as `ArrayList` that is being used to maintain that value.

> While populating the values using the adapter, you must use the above created `List` to assign values to the respective `View` in the `ListView`.

Hope that helps !!!